# Setting up PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have Scala and Spark installed and working but PySpark isn't working. Here's the out put Im getting:

```
user@ubuntu:~/spark$ pyspark 
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/spark/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 30, in <module>
    import pyspark
  File "pyspark.py", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sc' is not defined
```

Here's my `.bashrc`:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/home/user/spark
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have an import conflict. Somewhere in you path there is `pyspark.py` file which is picked before actual `pyspark` package.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't reproduce the problem but nevertheless didn't see why it's necessary to set the SPARK_HOME, PATH and PYTHONPATH.  If pyspark is started with path, then SparkContext should already be created.
If you start with ipython or python, you can use findspark package to locate Spark and create SparkContext

```
$ python
>>> import findspark
>>> findspark.init('/home/user/spark')
>>> from pyspark import SparkContext
>>> sc = SparkContext('local[4]', 'myapp')
```